# NoSuchMethodError when exporting a signed apk

Tags: android, deployment, compilation, dependencies, apk

I tried to compile [reddit-is-fun](https://github.com/talklittle/reddit-is-fun), a reddit reader for Android. If I start the application from ADT (either by debug or simply running) it will launch and run correctly on my phone (HTC Desire). However, if I export a signed and zipaligned package and install it, it will not work. The logcat shows NoSuchMethodError exceptions for [Jackson](https://jackson.codehaus.org/). It is two jars, present in the repository and added to the build path. I made sure that the two have the same versions and even replaced them with newer ones.

I'm not really familiar with using jar libraries. Are they "linked" into the resulting apk like a static library is linked to an executable when compiling C++? How can I make sure that the app on the device will load the same version used for compiling? (which is most likely the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Proguard obfuscation is breaking it. Try disabling Proguard to confirm (or add Jackson to the whitelist in `proguard.cfg`)

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the obfuscation. How can I whitelist an entire library? The problem is that the calls are obfuscated, but the library itself is not (I'm thinking this because the not found method is named like a.c.f.d).

Comment: You'll want to add a line something along the lines of `-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.*` to `proguard.cfg`.

Comment: Yeah it won't be exactly that, but along those lines.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure out which classes were broken. Later I found a note saying that a newer version of proguard is required so it doesn't break those classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that your JARs are not correctly translated from JVM format to Dalvik VM format. As you know Android uses different bytecode than ordinary desktop JVM. You should convert your JARs from JVM bytecode to Dalvik's bytecode. Try to Google "convert JVM to Dalvik"